# Send email on client's behalf using Gmail API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, authorization, gmail-api

So I have implemented Google login in my reactjs application using 
firebase.

I have added a form on the homepage where the user lands directly after signing in. I want the user to send form data to a particular vendor using his(user) Gmail. I know that I must use a different scope (i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send) for sending emails on user's behalf for the authorization purpose.Also, the permission should be asked only the first time while sending data.

I don't understand how can I implement this with react? I've already checked with the google and couldn't find anything useful. If there are any links or documentation which can help me, do let me know.

Below is the code.

index.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
    apiKey: "yourapikey",
    authDomain: "yourdomain.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "yourdatabase.firebaseio.com"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Header from './components/header'

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null
    }
    this.handleAuth = this.handleAuth.bind(this)
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user })
    })
  }

  handleAuth () {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(result => console.log(`${result.user.email} User signed in`))
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error.code}: ${error.message}`))
  }

  handleLogout () {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
      .then(result => console.log('user signed out'))
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error.code}: ${error.message}`))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          appName='Chat Real'
          user={this.state.user}
          onAuth={this.handleAuth}
          onLogout={this.handleLogout}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = ({ appName, user, onAuth, onLogout }) => {

  function renderUserData () {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className='navbar right'>
                <li>
                <img
                    width='32'
                    className='avatar circle responsive-img'
                    src={user.photoURL}
                />
                </li>
                <li>{user.displayName}</li>
                <li>
                <button
                    className='waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-1'
                    onClick={onLogout}
                >
                    Logout
                </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                <label>Title</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="title" /><br/>
                <label>Body</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="body" /><br/>
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
  }

  function renderLoginButton () {
    return (
      <ul className='right'>
        <li>
          <button
            className='waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-1'
            onClick={onAuth}
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )
  }

  return (
    <nav className='blue darken-4'>
      <div className='nav-wrapper container'>
        <a href='#' className='left brand-logo'>{appName}</a>
        {user ? renderUserData() : renderLoginButton()}
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Email sending is a serverside process, you can use `node.js` for that, or any other serverside language.

Answer (score 2):

Make below changes to your app.

1. First you've to ask user permission for sending mail in `handleAuth` function in `app.js` file. Reference for [scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes#gmail_scopes).

```js
handleAuth () {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send')

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(result => console.log(`${result.user.email} User signed in`))
        .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error.code}: ${error.message}`))
}
```

2. Change token management for firebase auth to get access token from OAuth2 received from *Google Sign-in*. You can [refer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) below code -

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...
        }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
});
```

3. Once you've token from user's sign in you can use the same to send mail via [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs). API supports nodejs and javascript as per your use case.

*Hope this helps*

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to add Google Cloud Platform Scopes and get the Access Token for cloud api calls.

Comment: @Vivek Can you expand on the issue? I'm trying to implement sending mechanism via gmail service in my electron application but having a hard time finding a sample code snippet

Comment: @Rixment You can use node npm package from [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) link

Comment: @Vivek Thanks for pointing it out but I've already check it. I'm using React/TS/Electron to create a desktop app and I need a sample code in order to dive into it quickly. If you can provide it I would be very grateful as I'm finding it hard googling it out